# detect runtime change in executable using debugger

Tags: c++, security, executable

I have a desktop application in c++. I want to check if any runtime change in the executable using debugger has been done or not. And if done executable will quit. How I check it?

I have already used CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent but hacker made changes in exe to skip this statement

edit: 
Can we forcefully stop debugger if it exists and if not it will just act as a dummy code. I have tried DebugActiveProcessStop but it doesnt work on current process i guess

Comment: What if you use a checksum and check that?

Comment: i am talking about runtime changes (in memory). how checksum is gonna work on that

Comment: @ashmish2: You can checksum memory just like you checksum everything else.

Comment: Note: Most modern OS will load the application part of the executable into read only memory thus it will not be possible to modify them (without doing something really funky with permission levels).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not generally possible to ensure that your executable is not modified.  You can opt for a secure platform (desktop applications are not) or you can get one of many code obfuscation / protection packages; but it is possible to bypass these.

My favorite essay on the subject is "Keeping the Pirates at Bay" ([source](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3030/keeping_the_pirates_at_bay.php)).

Answer (score 1):

To detect runtime changes you need a loop to hash various areas of memories to make sure they are unmodified along with something like [`VirtualQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make sure the page access isn't being tampered with, of course this can always be counteracted, just see Blizzards Warden (which uses this method).

Answer (score 1):

This recent paper by Tyler Shields from Veracode has a pretty extensive selection of techniques you could consider using.

http://www.shell-storm.org/papers/files/764.pdf

But you will have to accept that a sophisticated attacker will almost always find a way around whatever you choose to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679280%28VS.85%29.aspx) to detect a debugger, but I don't know if a way to detect if a change has been made. There are a few other options [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/Intro_To_Win_Anti_Debug.aspx).

Comment: I have done the same thing but the hacker made changes in exe to skip this statement :(

Comment: Would a hacker not also bypass your quit code? Once a debugger is attached, a process can be frozen and modified while in its frozen state, there is nothing it can do to prevent this.

Comment: exactly, so what the use of CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent() function then? i guess i cant execute this function !!